# Colorbox content not updating in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, colorbox

I am using Colorbox for a date popup and people have been saying to me that the content is not changing (I am using Chrome/FF on a Mac so no IE). Once I looked at it in IE8 I noticed that as soon as I change the value in a database and the windows content changes, IE8 does not show it. I do not have this problem in FF or Chrome.

Here is the content (generated by a PHP script):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mouseware.net/weekendcamping/includes/popupbox/colorbox.css" />
    <script src="http://mouseware.net/weekendcamping/includes/popupbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // Colorbox elements
            $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%", height:"50%"});$(".ajax").colorbox({width:"50%", height:"50%"});$(".ajax_lg").colorbox({width:"75%", height:"75%"});$(".ajax_tall").colorbox({width:"50%", height:"75%"});
        });
    </script>
                <div align="left" style="font-size:8pt;"><a href="http://mouseware.net/weekendcamping/administrator/index.php?option=reservations&act=selectDate&loc=1&height=400&width=400&dsptmpl=1" class="thickbox" style="font-size:8pt; color:#000000;">Location</a> &raquo; Date</div><br />
        <table align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" border="0" style="padding:0; margin:0;">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <div style="font-size:16pt; font-weight:bold;">Select Date</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
                                <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" onClick="$.colorbox.close(); updateEventDate('04/05/2013 - 04/07/2013')">04/05/2013 - 04/07/2013</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" onClick="$.colorbox.close(); updateEventDate('04/12/2013 - 04/14/2013')">04/12/2013 - 04/14/2013</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" onClick="$.colorbox.close(); updateEventDate('04/19/2013 - 04/21/2013')">04/19/2013 - 04/21/2013</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" onClick="$.colorbox.close(); updateEventDate('04/26/2013 - 04/28/2013')">04/26/2013 - 04/28/2013</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" onClick="$.colorbox.close(); updateEventDate('05/03/2013 - 05/05/2013')">05/03/2013 - 05/05/2013</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" onClick="$.colorbox.close(); updateEventDate('05/10/2013 - 05/12/2013')">05/10/2013 - 05/12/2013</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" onClick="$.colorbox.close(); updateEventDate('05/17/2013 - 05/19/2013')">05/17/2013 - 05/19/2013</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" onClick="$.colorbox.close(); updateEventDate('05/24/2013 - 05/26/2013')">05/24/2013 - 05/26/2013</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" onClick="$.colorbox.close(); updateEventDate('05/31/2013 - 06/02/2013')">05/31/2013 - 06/02/2013</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" onClick="$.colorbox.close(); updateEventDate('06/07/2013 - 06/09/2013')">06/07/2013 - 06/09/2013</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" onClick="$.colorbox.close(); updateEventDate('06/14/2013 - 06/16/2013')">06/14/2013 - 06/16/2013</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" onClick="$.colorbox.close(); updateEventDate('06/21/2013 - 06/23/2013')">06/21/2013 - 06/23/2013</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" onClick="$.colorbox.close(); updateEventDate('09/06/2013 - 09/08/2013')">09/06/2013 - 09/08/2013</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" onClick="$.colorbox.close(); updateEventDate('06/28/2013 - 06/30/2013')">06/28/2013 - 06/30/2013</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" onClick="$.colorbox.close(); updateEventDate('09/20/2013 - 09/22/2013')">09/20/2013 - 09/22/2013</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" onClick="$.colorbox.close(); updateEventDate('10/11/2013 - 10/13/2013')">10/11/2013 - 10/13/2013</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                </table>
```

It is being called from the mail file by

```
$.colorbox({href:'popupDate.php', width:'50%', height:'50%'})
```

My best guess is the popup windows is being cached in IE so it doesn't regenerate the content... but I am not sure.

I have updated the colorbox to the latest, 1.4.15, and jQuery to the latest, 1.9.1. Neither of these updates made a difference. I have also tried putting the content inside the  tags and  tags and that did not help. I also tried adding the no-cache HTML and PHP code to both my parent and the popup box... did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete IE temporary files (cache).

This worked for me.

Maybe you should send some no-cache headers for this page.

Comment: I tried "<meta http-equiv="cach-control" content="no-cache">" and it did not fix the problem.

Comment: try **PHP** headers:

[http://james.cridland.net/code/caching.html](http://james.cridland.net/code/caching.html)

Comment: Tried that, did not work. I still have the same problem with the page content changing but not reloading in IE8

Answer (score 0):

Add a timestamp or other unique variable every time to the href parameter. It will help you.

```
var seconds = new Date().getTime();
$.colorbox({href:'popupDate.php'+seconds});
```